# How to make some item unselectable in ListPreference

Tags: android, listpreference

At the PreferenceActivity has a listPreference. And I already setup the entries (e.g. "A" to "E") and entriesValues by programming method(not in xml).

is it possible to make some entry items unselectable which refer to the system version.

Answer (score 1):

For regular list items you may just return false for the 'boolean isEnabled (int position)'. This will make the item non clickable.

Comment: isEnabled can control listPreference. But my objective is listPreference's items A~E. for example: if API below than 9 , user can select A~D items (E will unselectable) only, otherwise user can select B~E items.

Answer (score 0):

Use setSelectable(false) on the Preference object. See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html